# Apache not reporting HTTPS server variable to PHP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, apache-config

Trying to get Apache 2.4.33 on an AWS EC2 instance to terminate an SSL certificate correctly, it doesn't seem to populate the `HTTPS` environment variable to PHP, and .htaccess rewrite rules don't work at all.

This is my setup:

/etc/httpd/conf/**httpd.conf**:

```
<Directory "/var/www/">
Options -Indexed +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

/etc/httpd/conf.d/**ssl.conf**:

```
Listen 443 https
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/cert.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/chain.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/httpd/conf.d/**vhosts.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
UseCanonicalPhysicalPort on
</VirtualHost>
```

/var/www/example.com/**.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine on

#if ELB http
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]

#if server http
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

#if www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

*Edit:* .htaccess has `-rw-rw-r--` permissions.

And this is what PHP reports:

1. for http://example.com (which for some reason is not enforced, despite .htaccess):

`$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = NULL`

`$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = '80'`

2. for https://example.com:

`$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = NULL`

`$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = '443'`

The only reason the port is correct is due to `UseCanonicalPhysicalPort`, but why is the HTTPS variable always null, and why doesn't .htaccess do anything?

**Edit:**
Per Patrick's comment, I've split the ports into one exclusive VirtualHost for each port, and removed the `UseCanonicalPhysicalPort` directive. This seems to have solved the first issue, and PHP now correctly displays both the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` and `SERVER_PORT` variables.

The second issue remains though: .htaccess rewrite rules are still not working.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: `.htaccess` files could be ignored depending on the `AllowOverride` directive. Or for permissions problems. In any case, if you can, it is better in all aspects to modify directly the core configuration files (including by using the `Include` directive) instead of using the `.htaccess` files. As for the other point, I am not sure a single virtualhost with both `*:80` and `*:443` is a good idea. I recommend you split this in two `VirtualHost` blocks. This may solve the HTTPS variable issue.

Comment: Thanks Patrick - I've updated OP with .htaccess permissions. I'll try splitting up the VirtualHost now.

Comment: @Patrick Splitting up the VirtualHosts solved the HTTPS variable issue, at least in PHP :) Thank you. Now just the mystery of .htaccess presumably not recognizing it remains. I'll have to try moving those rules into Apache, but I was wondering why it wasn't working this way.

Comment: Search for the `AllowOverride` and `AccessFileName` directives. Increase logging.  Put other things in `.htaccess` (than rewrite rules) to see if they are executed or not.